# Your theme has 1 widget areas, but this particular page doesn’t display them in wordpress

Tags: theme-customizer

Added sidebar by register_sidebar(),displayed it in pages through dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-id')

I want my customize-> widgets in admin panel should list the created widgets, please help me to resolve this.

Comment: So, here we have a duplicate question, to a Q/A that does not exists any more! Does anybody remembers what the answer was about?

Comment: Any solution to this? I am 
facing the same issue, created this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/288299/wordpress-your-theme-has-1-widget-area-but-this-particular-page-doesn-t-displ

Comment: The link for "already has answers here" is 404'd....